# How can I use javascript to add and remove an element over and over again?

Tags: javascript, firefox, internet-explorer-10, removechild

First posting.  I am attempting to use buttons defined in HTML to call a function that creates buttons via JavaScript while the other button removes the buttons created.

HTML:

```
<div id="thisdiv">
    <input type="button" onclick="makeButtons()" value="Add" />
    <input type="button" onclick="removeButtons()" value="Remove" />
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
function makeButtons()
{
var buttonOne=document.createElement("BUTTON");
var buttonTwo=document.createElement("BUTTON");

buttonOne.setAttribute("id", "yesdombutton"); //adds id to button
buttonTwo.setAttribute("id", "nodombutton"); //adds id to button

document.getElementById("thisdiv").appendChild(buttonOne); //appends buttons
document.getElementById("thisdiv").appendChild(buttonTwo);
}

function removeButtons()
{   
var div = document.getElementById("thisdiv");

div.removeChild(yesdombutton);     //this works only once in firefox but >
div.removeChild(nodombutton);      //works over and over in IE
}
```

As the comment sin the remove() function state, the code as is only works once in Firefox, but works fine in IE10.  And by work, I mean that I can click the Yes and No buttons in the HTML section, back and forth, and the buttons created by the JavaScript appear and disappear as they should.

I would like the same to occur in Firefox but I have been unable to find an answer.

Comment: where are you defining `yesdombutton` and `nodombutton` ?

Comment: Also where are you defining `textOne` and `textTwo`?

Comment: @Alnitak - `yesdombutton` and `nodombutton` are defined in `makeButtons()`.

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy - I apologize, I meant to take that code out since it was used only to add what text appears on the buttons, editing now!

Answer (score 0):

And a friend of mine mentioned that I have a scope issue...  The following code makes the site work like how I want it to.

Javascript:

```
function removeButtons()
{
var div = document.getElementById("albumown");
var destroyMe = document.getElementById("yesdombutton");   //This makes it so that
var destroyMeToo = document.getElementById("nodombutton"); //the buttons I want to
                                                           //remove are referenced
div.removeChild(destroyMe);                                //correctly
div.removeChild(destroyMeToo);
}
```

Thank you to those that asked about this!  I have been wracking my head for a week trying different things.  But, all is well now.